# How do you make a Node.js application refresh every minute with nohup?

Tags: node.js

Hey guys I have a node app that needs to run in the background and restart every minute. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have a feeling this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I agree. I'm reposting this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "crontab -e" and add this line:

```
* * * * * nohup nodejs <node_app_name> &
```